# Strava API - Segment effort_count inconsistencies

Tags: strava

I realise this might not be the right place for this question, but mailing list is silent, maybe there is bigger audience here.

I am using getSegmentById endpoint of strava API to daily fetch the `effort_count` for a number of segments. I have noticed that occasionally there are random fluctuations on the numbers that come back. One day the effort_count was lower on a couple of segments than the day before. On a different day, almost all the segments had a huge jump in the counts, too big to be real (i.e segments with typical numbers of 10-20 efforts per day had 500 on that day).

Anyone has any explanation on this? Or is there a better place to target those questions, given that the API mailing list has given no response?

The mailing list topic: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/strava-api/cJZyoGl49AU

Here is a screenshot of the `effort_count` diff between dates. Negative numbers showing up randomly. Counts are recorded at 11PM UTC..

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the past I had a similar problem with segment leaderboard API that sometimes returned wrong position of the authenticated user.

I solved this problem using a trick found on google groups (`context_entries` parameter).

After [changes to segment API](http://developers.strava.com/docs/segment-changes/), this trick didn't work anymore and I had to analyze data returned from Strava: if something seemed strange I simply retry the request after a little timeout; it usually solved in 2-3 tries. Maybe this trick also works with `effort_count`.

Comment: Have you managed to find any explanation on this inconsistency ? I could change the code to retry if the API results are extremely off the average, but it feels strange that I'd need to do that...

Comment: Never investigated the problem; opened a ticket with Strava support but in the end I used this trick: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/strava-api/Z884GXNwqNU

Comment: I forgot to mention that segment leaderboad problem occasionally appeared also in official strava app and website. Did you notice this for segment efforts count?

Comment: I have been using the leaderboard for counts before the API changes and it was working fairly reliably. That API allowed for retrieving counts for  "today", and there never has been a negative value. FIrst time I saw a negative value was on 18th of June 2020.